# how to set onItemClick as well as OnTouchListener to the view

Tags: android, animation, gesture

I have a `View` in which I set a list using `ListAdapter`. Now I want to swipe a `View` using `OnTouchListener`, but as soon as I touch the `View`, the `onItemClickListener` method gets fired.

I tried adding both `OnTouchListener` and `onItemClickListener` to the `View` but only `OnTouchListner` seems to be fired. Please help me so that I can swipe the whole `View` as well as have the ability to to add items to the `View` on a click.

Comment: You can use ViewPage for that...

Comment: check [this][1] answer:I think it will be helpfull


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13081250/android-buttons-clickevent-of-listview-using-baseadapter/13081773#13081773

Comment: I think @Syed's answer covered that.. If that doesn't work for you.. just comment i will paste my code here...

Comment: hmmmmcan u share the code Amit?

Answer (score 1):

I think click will not work only touch event will be fired. You can try touch with long click or see links below

[Can't handle both click and touch events simultaneously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5159366/cant-handle-both-click-and-touch-events-simultaneously)

Or have a look at [ViewPager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html) or [Android-ViewPagerIndicator](https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator)