# List view layout similar to call log of android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, calllog

i want to create a layout just similar to
[image]

for this i am creating a layout for the row of ListView.
can you please describe me what are the components they are using to create this row's layout.

below is the coding that i am using to create row of ListView.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="8dp" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        tools:ignore="UseCompoundDrawables" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/callDetailName"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="name"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/callDetailType"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
            tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/callDetailNumber"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="number"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/callDetailTime"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmallInverse"
            tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@android:drawable/dark_header"
    tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/callBackBtn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="#00000000"
    android:minWidth="50dp"
    android:src="@android:drawable/sym_action_call"
    tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />
```

Comment: it is correct. What you want ?

Comment: as you can see, that row is saperated in two parts, one for call detail and another for Button to call, so the problem is i am not getting the event from the first part and Button.

Comment: check have you placed correct Id in program. Designing is correct I think, problm with your code

Comment: not getting whats the problem is there, i am setting onItemClickListener to the listView

Comment: your setting onclick listner for particular row. not fot button. google it how to work with listviews child buttons listner.

Comment: yaa, right, i think, i should set the onClickListener where intilizing these layout elements. thanks a lot @TechEnd for you suggestions

Comment: now i am setting onClickListener in getView, but another problem is comming, i unable to get the postion of element in listView.

Comment: are you working with BaseAdapter ??

Comment: check this answers n try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13081250/android-buttons-clickevent-of-listview-using-baseadapter

Comment: in the above link, in onClick(View v) they are matching view withe clicked view id.
but i want to get the position in the listView

Comment: using getView() you can get the position. goto last 15-20 lines of  this blog http://imagelistviewdynamic.blogspot.in/ .. this might help you out. Its my blog with working example.