# onItemClickListener is not working, not getting event when i click

Tags: android, android-listview, onitemclicklistener

I am using custom Adapter for the `ListView`, setting row every time in the `ListView`.
in row i want to have two view clickable, i want the click event from both.
setting `OnItemClickListener` to the `ListView`, but not working,
i want the functionality exactly same as callLog list view (default in the phone).
please solve my problem, if you want i can paste my code here too.

```
package com.example.testsmspopup;
```

public class CallLogActivity extends Activity {

```
private ArrayList<CallDetail> callDetailArrayList;
private ListView callDetailListView = null;
private CallDetailListAdapter callDetailListAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    callDetailListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.contactListView);
    callDetailListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
            Log.i("MyTag","calling ...........................");
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "onItemClick is calling", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();
    callDetailArrayList = DB.getInstance(this).getAllCallDetails();
    callDetailListAdapter = new CallDetailListAdapter();
    callDetailListView.setAdapter(callDetailListAdapter);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.call_detail_activity, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.menu_clear_all) {
        DB.getInstance(this).deleteAllCallDetails();
    }
    return true;
}

private class CallDetailListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<CallDetail> {
    public CallDetailListAdapter() {
        super(CallLogActivity.this, R.layout.call_log_row, callDetailArrayList);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        CallDetailHolder holder = null;
        if (row == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.call_log_row, parent, false);
            holder = new CallDetailHolder(row);
            row.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (CallDetailHolder) row.getTag();
        }
        holder.populateFrom(callDetailArrayList.get(position));
        return (row);
    }
}

private class CallDetailHolder {
    private TextView nameTextView = null;
    private TextView numTextView = null;
    private TextView timeTextView = null;
    private ImageView typeImageView = null;

    public CallDetailHolder(View row) {
        nameTextView = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.callDetailName);
        numTextView = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.callDetailNumber);
        timeTextView = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.callDetailTime);
        typeImageView = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.callDetailType);
```

//          row.findViewById(R.id.callDetail).setOnClickListener(CallLogActivity.this);
//          row.findViewById(R.id.callBackBtn).setOnClickListener(CallLogActivity.this);
        }

```
    public void populateFrom(CallDetail detail) {
        String fName = DB.getInstance(CallLogActivity.this).getContact(detail.getCallNumber()).getFirstName();
        String lName = DB.getInstance(CallLogActivity.this).getContact(detail.getCallNumber()).getLastName();
        nameTextView.setText(fName + " " + lName);
        numTextView.setText(detail.getCallNumber());
        timeTextView.setText(AppUtility.parseCallTime(detail.getCallTime()));
        switch (detail.getCallType()) {
        case AppConstants.INCOMING_CALL:
            typeImageView.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.sym_call_incoming);
            break;
        case AppConstants.OUTGOING_CALL:
            typeImageView.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.sym_call_outgoing);
            break;
        case AppConstants.MISS_CALL:
            typeImageView.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.sym_call_missed);
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: yes do please paste the code.

Comment: @AndroSelva: please check it, i've paste the code

Comment: show us call_log_row.xml

Comment: plesae find it here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14121601/list-view-layout-similar-to-call-log-of-android#comment19751568_14121601

Answer (score 2):

For Showing Toast inside onItemClick() method Write

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "onItemClick is calling", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

instead

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "onItemClick is calling", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have an `ImageButton` in your list item. It is `focusable` and it's prevents entire item from click events. In order to get click event for list item you have to set an `ImageButton` as non focusable. Note that you have to do it in the code but not in `xml`.

Just add this code in your `CallDetailHolder` constructor and it should work well:

```
ImageButton callBackButton = (ImageButton) row.findViewById(R.id.callBackBtn);
callBackButton.setFocusable(false);
```

Comment: i added this line in CallDetailHolder(View row) {
row.findViewById(R.id.callBackBtn).setFocusable(false);

Comment: yes, i have made a small mistake. `ImageButton` has `R.id.callBackBtn` id. Is it works now?

Comment: now onItemClickListener is invoking, but when i click on Button, it doesn't invoke

Comment: i want the behavior just similar to android's callLog List

Comment: You haven't set any `OnClickListener` for an `ImageButton`

Comment: but in onClickListener i'll get the the position in ListView, actually i've to get the whole data depending on which row clicked

Comment: You can set `onClickListener` in `getView` method. Current item position is passed as an argument